# Django Manytomany filter with intermediate model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following models:

```
class Personne(BaseModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    relations = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='PersonneRelation',
                                       symmetrical=False,
                                       related_name='personne_relations')

class PersonneRelation(BaseModel):
    type_relation = models.IntegerField(
        choices=[(a, b) for a, b in list(PersonneEnums.TAB_RELATIONS.items())],
        default=PersonneEnums.RELATION_FRIEND)
    src = models.ForeignKey('Personne', related_name='relation_src')
    dst = models.ForeignKey('Personne', related_name='relation_dst')
```

In my view, I have the currently logged user via

```
p_user = Personne.objects.get(user=view.request.user)
```

I want to retrieve all the relation of `p_user` that are of type `PersonneEnums.RELATION_FRIEND`

I've tried many things including the following code, but nothing works:

Doesn't work :

```
p_user.objects.filter(relations__type_relation__exact=PersonneEnums.RELATION_AMI)
```

Doesn't work:

```
Personne.objects.filter(
    pk=p_user.pk,
    relations__type_relation__exact=PersonneEnums.RELATION_AMI
)
```

Can someone explain to me why this does not work?

Comment: What does "doesnt work" mean? errors? invalid results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases you're trying to use the default manager `objects`, while you need to use a relationship manager. However it seems, that there will be a problem as relationship is ambiguous, i.e. when querying relationship like this:

```
p_user.relations.filter(type_relation=PersonneEnums.RELATION_AMI)
```

Django couldn't decide if it should use `src` or `dst` in this query.

The following query should work:

```
PersonneRelations.objects.filter(
    Q(type_relation=PersonneEnums.RELATION_AMI), Q(src=p_user) | Q(dst=p_user))
```

also, something like this might work (see explanation on [`filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)):

```
p_user.relations.filter(relation_src__type_relation=PersonneEnums.RELATION_AMI
               ).filter(relation_dst__type_relation=PersonneEnums.RELATION_AMI)
```

Comment: If I try your solution, I get this error: `Cannot resolve keyword 'type_relation' into field. Choices are: ...(list of all the properties of the model **Personne**)`

Comment: If I try `p_user.relations.filter(
            relations__type_relation=PersonneEnums.RELATION_AMI
        )` I get: `TypeError at /xx Related Field got invalid lookup: type_relation`

Comment: @OliverPons, please see last answer update, had to make several edits, but this should do the trick.

Comment: Ok thank you very much, I found it almost when you wrote your answer: I used the `PersonneRelations.objects.filter()` thing, but my query is far more complex because the `src` could be `p_user` but the `dst` could be `p_user` as well (= if the current user invited someone or was being invited) so I had to (1) do a query to extract all `src` relations (2) another query to extract all `dst` relations, (2) join both queries and keep only the `Personne` results that were `RELATION_AMI`. Such complex query.. and very hard to explain the complexity to my client